# Computationnal Mechanics : Three Bodies contact problem with ALM

Tags: convergence, computational-mechanics

I am facing an issue with convergence of a contact problem consisting of three successive bars, as presented below. [image]

A force is applied on the right hand of the first bar so there is contact between both the first and the second bar and the second and the third bar. Another bar is linked to the second bar so there is no ill-conditionned stiffness matrix.

I implemented a Python code to solve this problem using the Augmented Lagrange Multiplier Method with Uzawa's algoritm to update the Lagrangian Multipliers, as presented in Yastrebov, "Numerical Methods in Contact Mechanics".

As it stands now, I am able to solve this problem using my code, generating the expected results.

Nonetheless, I am not satisfied with the convergence the ALM provides for this problem, and I am looking for a way to improve it. Also, the robustness of ALM for this problem is poor, in such way that a sligth modification in penalty prevents the convergence.

I am looking for a way to improve both robustness and convergence of this problem.

One way I found that worked for other problems but not for this one, is to update the contact forces before updating the displacements, and looping again on  to converge Lagrangian Multipliers. This way, the system anticipates the contact forces. For a reason I don't understand, this method works for other problems, reducing the total amount of iterations, but it prevents this particular problem from converging.

**Edit :**

The algorithm is constituted of two loops :
First loop regards the update of the displacements
Second loop is inner to the first one and regards the update of the Lagrange Mulipliers.
I'll use the superscipt $i$ to refer to the i-th iteration of the first loop and $j$ to refer to the j-th iteration of the second loop.

Given an initial displacement $u = 0$, the penalty $\epsilon$, the Lagrange Multiplier $\lambda=0$ and the gap function of a contact $G = x_2 - x_1$ and given the contact force : $F_c = max(\lambda - \epsilon \times G, 0)$

First Loop :

1. Computing the Residuals $R^i = R(u^i) = \sum\left(F_i(u^i) + F_e(u^i) + F_c(u^i) \right) $ : sum of internal, external and contact forces.
2. Computing a descent direction $v^i$
3. Second loop

   1. Compute the step $\rho^j$ minimizing the energy $W(u+v^i*\rho^j)$
   2. Update the Lagrange Multiplier : $\lambda^{j+1} = \lambda^j - \epsilon \times G$
   3. **If** ($G - \rho^j\times v^i > 0$ and $\epsilon \times (G - \rho^j\times v^i)< Tol^j$) or $j = j^{max}$ **go to 4** . **Else** $j = j+1 $and **go to 3**.
4. $u^{i+1} = u^i + \rho^j\times v^i$ and $x^{i+1} = x^i+u^{i+1}$
5. **If** $R(u^{i+1}) < Tol^i$ or $i = i^{max}$ **end**. **Else** $i = i+1$

I do not mind doing more iterations of the inner loop. Yet I would like to minimize the number of iterations from the first loop.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Please state your question a bit more explicitly. Can you state the equations for the iteration you are currently using?

Comment: Done. I hope you find it precise enough